# How to transfer notes on the iPhone between different IMAP account?

Tags: iphone, notes.app

After adding a new email account (call it gmail-2), my default note app account has been accidentally changed to the new gmail account(gmail-2). I did not realize it until after tons of notes to it. So right now I have two accounts on my iPhone both have a lots of notes. So I wonder is there any way that I can transfer the all notes in the gmail-2 to the old account(call it gamil-1) automatically without copying all of them by hand?

Answer (score 1):

I asked apple, the response is that there is no other way than copy and paste.